# Picasso Target Error: method BitmapDrawable is undefined for type new Target()

Tags: android, undefined, picasso

I'm using Picasso to pull a jpg from a URL and then append to an EditText. As can be seen I am using the Target method to input the image from the URL into my Drawable, which is then appended to my EditText. However, an error occurs:

```
The method BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap) is undefined for the type new Target(){}
```

at location:

```
BitmapDrawable(getBaseContext().getResources(), bitmap);
```

What appears to be going wrong? How is this Target class implementation properly configured for my actions?

Method to append to EditText:

```
public void appendToMessageHistory(final String username,
            final String message) {
        if (username != null && message != null) {

            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load("http://localhost:3000/uploads/campaign/image/2/2.jpg").into(new Target() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
                    Drawable drawImage = BitmapDrawable(
                            getBaseContext().getResources(), bitmap);
                    messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + username
                            + ":" + "</b>" + "<br>"));
                    messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml(message + "<hr>"
                            + "<br>")
                            + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "");

                    messageHistoryText.append(Html.fromHtml("<img src = '"
                            + drawImage + "'/>", imageGetter, null));
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you forgot the `new` keyword before `BitmapDrawable`.

```
Drawable drawImage = BitmapDrawable(
                        getBaseContext().getResources(), bitmap);
```

should be

```
Drawable drawImage = new BitmapDrawable(
                        getBaseContext().getResources(), bitmap);
```

Comment: Well that allowed the error to go away, but it killed he method and it will not work. I will put another question up